# How would I grep my git log to just show the commit messages, comma separated?

Tags: git, grep

How can I `grep` my `git log` to show commit messages comma separated for use in invoicing?

Comment: Don't use the `--pretty`/`--format` option instead. See the man page/documentation.

Comment: What sort of output do you desire?  Any command line will do?

Comment: Yes, I want my commit messages comma separated so I can pipe into pbcopy and paste into my invoice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (If you do not have a commit range, then leave it out):

```
git log --pretty='%s' <range> | tr '\n' ','
```

Comment: @quantumpotato The `<range>` is not meant to be taken literally. It should be the range of commits that you want to list. Leave it out if you do not care to limit the commits you will list.

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --since "AUG 26 2019" --until "SEP 02 2019" --pretty=format:"%an,%ad,%s" > log.csv
```

The log.csv is a file to output to. To display on screen remove the > and everything thereafter.

Key

- %an is the author name
- %ad is the full date time
- %s is the commit
  message

Optionally you can add %h for the abbreviated commit hash, just remember to separate with a comma.

[See this cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/git-log-format)